# Regex for everything between two strings (first string has character at end)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a regex to return everything between two strings, however the first string contains a character at the end. I am able to get the text between two strings, but not sure how to do it if the first string has a character at the end.

https://regex101.com/r/eZ1gT7/945

For example:
`Testing | Hello World | Another test`

I want to be able to get `Hello World`.

Comment: your regex and your example aren't even similar

Answer (score 0):

If it's always "Something | Something | Something", then `.*\s\|(.*)\s\|.*` would get whatever is in between the two |.

https://regex101.com/r/eZ1gT7/947